# Подскажите как перебрать массив но при этом удаляя каждый раз взятое значение?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Подскажите, как перебрать массив, но при этом удаляя каждый раз взятое значение? У меня есть код, который берет значение из массива, но при этом он не удаляет взятый элемент из массива. А мне нужно, чтобы каждый раз бралось новое значение.

```
const finish = require('collections/list');

let muList = ['81.16.2.201:8080','45.170.68.200:8080','45.248.42.200:8080','45.182.66.202:8080','177.66.174.202:8080']
 fer = muList.peek();

console.log(fer);
```

Comment: `while(muList.length){console.log(muList.pop())}`

Comment: Ваш пример выводит весь массив а нужно одно значение а потом   вывести следующие, вопрос как сделать как взять новое значение ?

Comment: пример выводит не весь массив, а несколько раз `while = цикл` по одному элементу, при этом удаляя их из массива `muList.pop()`

Comment: let muList = ['81.16.2.201:8080','45.170.68.200:8080','45.248.42.200:8080','45.182.66.202:8080','177.66.174.202:8080']


while(muList.length ){console.log(muList.pop())}
в webstorm выводит весь массив

Answer (score 0):

```js
let myList = ['81.16.2.201:8080','45.170.68.200:8080','45.248.42.200:8080','45.182.66.202:8080','177.66.174.202:8080']

Array.prototype.peek = function() {
  return this.shift() // Удаляет первый элемент из массива и возвращает его
}

// Здесь по строке задачи видно, что запилен кастомный метод массивов "peek", который и должен все делать.
// Его и нужно реализовать, он выше

let fer = myList.peek();

// Проверка 

console.log(fer, myList);
```